# RedHat / CentOS 5.5 background process has restricted memory

Tags: linux, background-process, out-of-memory

I run Fisheye that uses Java for Linux. Settings go like this:

#### generate options

```
FISHEYE_OPTS=`$JAVACMD -Xms100m -Xmx200m -cp $FISHEYE_HOME/fisheyeboot.jar com.cenqua.fisheye.boot.OptsSetter`
```

#### build fisheye command

```
FISHEYE_CMD="$JAVACMD $FISHEYE_OPTS -Xms100m -Xmx200m -Dfisheye.library.path=$FISHEYE_LIBRARY_PATH -Dfisheye.inst=$FISHEYE_INST -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=$FISHEYE_HOME/lib/endorsed -jar $FISHEYE_HOME/fisheyeboot.jar"
```

#### Then I run:

```
cd $FISHEYE_INST
mkdir -p $FISHEYE_INST/var/log
nohup sh -c "exec $FISHEYE_CMD $@ $FISHEYE_ARGS >> $FISHEYE_INST/var/log/fisheye.out 2>&1" &
```

So  the **nohup** command runs the program in the background. It doesn't start, saying: "out of memory" or something about the heap file.

However, when I just do `exec $FISHEYE_CMD $@ $FISHEYE_ARGS` it works fine, yet it's not in the background.

So I'm wondering how I can allow it to use more memory when I run it in in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the exec command in your example. Can you try the nohup line without it? Try this:

```
nohup sh -c "$FISHEYE_CMD $@ $FISHEYE_ARGS >> $FISHEYE_INST/var/log/fisheye.out 2>&1" &
```

If the above doesn't work you may want to try using `bash` instead of `sh`. Try this:

```
nohup bash -c "$FISHEYE_CMD $@ $FISHEYE_ARGS >> $FISHEYE_INST/var/log/fisheye.out 2>&1" &
```

Finally if neither of these suggestions work, I'd try getting rid of the "shell -c" argument all together. Try this:

```
nohup "$FISHEYE_CMD $@ $FISHEYE_ARGS >> $FISHEYE_INST/var/log/fisheye.out 2>&1" &
```

#### References

- You can read more about the Bash builtins here - [Bash manual on shell builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).
- A blog post I wrote up a couple of years ago about the [proper use of nohup](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/2349/one-liner-how-to-properly-use-nohup/#more-2349).